# AWS API gateway : Changing Missing Authentication Token response for the HTTP operation which is not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS API gateway and AWS lambda function.

When I invoke the API through the client like Postman and specify the HTTP operation, I get an error -

```
Response code: 401
Response:
{ "message": "Missing Authentication Token" }
```

Ideally I should receive an error -  Response code 405 [Method not allowed]

Is there any way this can be configured?

Answer (score 1):

Gateway Responses allow you to customize errors that are generated by API Gateway before the request reaches your backend. There is a `MISSING_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN` response type which you can use for your use case.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/customize-gateway-responses.html